# Is my US visa still valid after change in name?

Tags: visas, usa, passports

I'm a Malawian national and I got US Visa years back.

Recently, due to some reasons, I had to get my first name partially changed on my passport. I have got an affidavit certificate stating the reason and proof.

Since the visa on my old passport has still not expired, but there is a difference in first name, will I face any problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems you won't have a problem with this, just make sure you carry the official documentation about your name change. It's also very common to carry two passports, the old one with the valid visa and a newer one.

Quoting the US [embassy](https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/non-immigrant-visa-faqs/visas-application-procedures-validity-and-length-of-stay/):

> A change of name will not affect the validity of the visa.  We
>   recommend that when traveling, you carry a copy of the document
>   showing the name change.

Answer (score 3):

My passport had clerical error in my name which they corrected in the new passport. I had following scenario:

```
Old passport:
Last Name - Blank
First Name - John Smith 

Valid US visa on old passport: 
Surname - John Smith
First Name - FNU

New Passport:
Last Name: Smith
First name : John
```

I breezed through the immigration. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I traveled on a passport with my maiden name and just brought the documentation with me - you should be fine!